# jQuery - Moving one element after another element of it's parent

Tags: jquery, append, insertafter

I want a code that moves the span in item-2 to after of span in item-1. I want this transition to happen in the parent element of each span, i.e. items-wrapper

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="items-wrapper">
    <div class="item-1">
        <span>element</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
        <span>element</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="items-wrapper">
    <div class="item-1">
        <span>element</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
        <span>element</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

my code

```
$(".item-2 span").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().insertAfter(".item-1 span");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the question and added my code

Comment: In your code, you are moving not the span, but it's parent. Moreover you do not limit the .item-1 span to corresponding wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. `parent()` goes only 1 step ahead so as per your requirement, `$(this).parent().parent().find(".item-1");` to find actual dom to use `insertAfter`.

Example:

```js
$(".item-2 span").each(function() {
  var elm = $(this).parent().parent().find(".item-1 span");
  $(this).insertAfter(elm);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="items-wrapper">
    <div class="item-1">
      <span>element</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
      <span>element</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="items-wrapper">
    <div class="item-1">
      <span>element</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
      <span>element</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Alternative using `appendTo()` which insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target.

Example:

```js
$(".item-2 span").each(function() {
  var elm = $(this).parent().parent().find(".item-1");
  $(this).appendTo(elm);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="items-wrapper">
    <div class="item-1">
      <span>element</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
      <span>element</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="items-wrapper">
    <div class="item-1">
      <span>element</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
      <span>element</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```